# Do we need to maintain different instances of state machine for each transaction

Tags: spring-boot, spring-statemachine

We are analyzing state machine to implement in one of our micro services solutions (spring boot).

Service is handling transactions, and internally calling other payment providers APIs. My concern is do we have to create separate instances of state machines with respect to transactionId.

Any leads would be appreciated.